# How to generate uniformly distributed random floating point numbers on entire possible range in matlab

Tags: matlab, random, floating-point, numbers

I am trying to generate an array of uniformly distributed floating point values in single precision in MATLAB.

I want to generate all numbers in the range +/- (2-2^-23)*2^127 which represents the range of possible 32-bit floating point numbers based on the IEEE-754 standard.  The problem is that only large magnitude numbers are being generated, and I want small magnitude numbers (near and including 0) to be included as well.  This is seen if we take the absolute value of all numbers generated and then find the smallest (I have copied the output below the code).

So far I have this code in MATLAB:

```
numtogenerate = 20000;

% Preallocate for speed
generatednumber(numtogenerate) = 0;

for i = 1:numtogenerate
   generatednumber(i) =  rand*(2-2^-23)*2^127*2 - 2^127*(2-2^-23); 
end

minimum = min(generatednumber)
smallest = min(abs(generatednumber))
maximum = max(generatednumber)

hist(generatednumber)
```

Here is the output:

```
minimum =

 -3.4026e+038


smallest =

  8.4046e+033


maximum =

  3.4027e+038
```

Comment: You generate large numbers because you are subtracting two numbers whose magnitudes are around 2^127. At that magnitude, the least significant bit in the 32-bit IEEE 754 format is 2^104. So the smallest difference between any two numbers of that magnitude is 2^104, and it is not possible for the subtraction to produce smaller numbers.

Comment: Do you want the distribution to have uniform density over the “real” numbers covered by the floating-point range (i.e., to approximate what an actual continuous uniform distribution over the reals would have) or uniform density over the representable numbers (each representable number has equal probability)? In the former case, you will generate mostly large numbers because most numbers are large.

Comment: another way to think of what @Eric said is the following, in each round of `rand` you have 90% to get a number between 0.1 and 1, this will translate to number in the 1e+38 range...

Comment: I appreciate your advice, but I would like the generator to be able to produce numbers such as 1.2 for example and that isn't happening.  Do you have solution to make this possible?

Comment: @starbox: You must answer the question about what distribution you want. Do you want each representable value (including subnormals?) with equal probability, or do you want each representable value with probability proportional to an interval it “represents” in some sense (approximate a uniform distribution over the reals)?

Comment: @EricPostpischil, I do not want subnormal values. I basically want to be able to form a histogram plot with a nearly flat distribution whilst still including small values.  So I want each value to be equally probable, regardless of the interval it represents.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

(Why in the name of god and little green apples would you do this in a loop?)

My point is, do it using the capabilities of MATLAB. Learn to use vectors and arrays. Apply operations to an entire array of numbers. This is how a tool like MATLAB shines. Until you do, you might as well be using a lower level language, but without the speed benefits gained from using that lower level tool.

Ok, rant over, so how do we attack this problem?

Generate each number using THREE different random values.

1. A random sign
2. A random exponent
3. A random mantissa

Do it all using vector ops.

```
numtogenerate = 20000;

% the sign
S = (rand(numtogenerate,1) < 0.5)*2 - 1;

% The exponent
E = floor(rand(numtogenerate,1)*256) - 128;

% The mantissa
M = rand(numtogenerate,1)*2 - 2^-23;

% bring it all together
R = S.*M.*2.^E;
```

Do they cover the entire range? It seems so.

```
min(abs(R))
ans =
      7.44202895026248e-41

max(R)
ans =
      3.17337113940593e+38

min(R)
ans =
      -3.3810631675676e+38
```

Assuming I got the ranges correct for each part, this should essentially generate every possible value in the desired range.

By the way, these are NOT uniformly distributed numbers, at least NOT in the way that term is usually applied in mathematics.

Comment: (0) This does not generate subnormal values, except for the error in the exponent range. (1) The normal exponent range is -126 to 127, but this generates -128 to 127 (if my guesses about MATLAB `rand` and such are correct). (2) If the `rand` range is [0, 1), then unnormalized significands are generated, distorting the distribution. (3) The fraction portion is better called a significand (linear) not a mantissa (logarithmic).

Comment: @woodchips, thank you for your answer and your rant.  I did this in a loop because it was the quickest way to think about the problem, but I am fully aware of vectors to perform operations faster lol.  Anyway, Is there anyway to make this distribution uniform? In one of my many iterations of this problem I arrived at the same solution as you, but the numbers aren't uniformly distributed.

Comment: @EricPostpischil - Yes, I knew I was being sloppy about the subnormals. Better perhaps is to generate the numbers in hex form.

Comment: @woodchips, also, what about what Eric said regarding the exponent range? Is it possible to fix that?

Comment: @starbox - as much as you SAY that you want a "uniform" distribution, you don't really want what it implies (based on your initial question.) If you truly do want a uniform distribution, then the odds will indeed be tiny that you will ever see a truly small number.

Comment: @woodchips, Thank you, do you have any fix for the exponent range?

Comment: Given the criteria so far, I suggest: Generate exponents from -126 to 127, with a uniform distribution. Generate significands as `rand(…)+1` but, if the result is exactly 2 (due to rounding), change it to 1 (which compensates for 1 being otherwise shortchanged by rounding). This assumes `rand` essentially generates a uniform distribution over the values `i/2^24` for `i` in [0, 2^24). If it does not, adjustments are needed. If so, I expect this to generate each representable finite, normal, non-zero value with equal probability. It will not generate, zeroes, subnormals, or infinities.

Comment: Zeroes and subnormals could easily be included by letting the exponent go from -127 to 127 but treating -127 as special: For each case where the exponent is -127, change it to -126 and subtract one from the significand (making it unnormalized). If you wanted to generate zeroes but not subnormals or vice versa, or you wanted to include infinities, then the numbers of values with each exponent are unequal, and you have to change the algorithm to skew for this.

Comment: +1 for the rant, applicable to so many Matlab questions in these parts.

Comment: @woodchips, I appreciate you taking the time to answer this question, but long story short, you have no way of doing what I asked about in terms of each possible floating point number being equally as likely to be generated?

Comment: @woodchips, the mean is also far from zero, even after 2000000 values, it still hangs around -3.1405e+033

Comment: @Starbox - Sigh. Again, I think you do not understand what a uniform distribution means. If EVERY possible value is equally likely to occur, then the arithmetic mean MUST be that large. As I have posted it (with some minor modifications to get it right) this DOES generate every possible value with equal probability. But that is NOT a uniform distribution.

Comment: @woodchips, I sincerely thank you for helping me out, I'm just trying to understand everything you're saying since I plan to test a floating point addition unit using randomly generated values, so I thought the equal probability for every value was best.  I do not care about subnormal values.  I also really don't comprehend why the mean can't be 0 if that is the case.  I guess this isn't a uniform distribution because it doesn't have "all intervals of the same length on the distribution's support being equally probable". If you know something better than what I described, please let me know.

Comment: @starbox - Yes, this distribution does not put equal weight on equal intervals. As far as the mean being zero, this is a SAMPLE mean you are computing, but of a distribution with obscenely long tails. The sample mean in this case will have very poor properties. Distributions like this do not behave nicely like a normal distribution, or a true uniform distribution.

Comment: @starbox: How do you calculate the mean? Do you take many random numbers generated by this method, add them, and divide by the number of them? That will not calculate the mean because some of the numbers will be very large, and the precision of floating-point is unable to store the sum precisely enough to include the contributions of the smaller numbers to the sum. Additionally, I would expect the true mean of a sample of numbers generated this way to often be quite large, even if the mean of the distribution is exactly zero, because samples will often have large numbers that do not balance.

Comment: @starbox: If you are testing a floating-point addition unit, you should include subnormals. And you should not use just random samples; you should use test cases carefully crafted to test for likely bugs in floating-point addition, including numbers near boundaries (near infinity, near the subnormal-normal transition, near zero, numbers that sum to a value that rounds up to the next exponent transition, et cetera).

Comment: @EricPostpischil, I just use the mean() function in MATLAB to calculate the mean.  Also, I do not plan to include support for subnormals since I do not expect them to make appearances in my application.  I do agree that I should use carefully tested inputs, but I am just trying to see average, minimum, and maximum number of cycles for an add, subtract, multiply, cosine, sine, divide, square root.  Are there any applications you know of that require subnormal inputs?...My platform will not handle exceptions.

Comment: @starbox: You might test the `mean` function in MATLAB by asking it for the mean of {-(2**100), 1, 2**100}. If it returns 0, it cannot handle sets of numbers with greatly varying magnitudes. If it returns 1, it might, but other sets might reveal a weakness in `mean`. A common way to encounter subnormals is with a function intended to provide echo/reverb effects. An echo commonly repeats the signal with lower and lower magnitudes. When the input becomes silent, the previous input continues lowering until it reaches subnormals. There are other ways to encounter subnormals.